# Overloading fork( )

Tags: c, linux, fork, system-calls

I have overloaded the `fork()` system call and created my own version of `fork()` using RTLD_NEXT. That is, `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, fork)`. This will hit my version of fork. After this I want to replicate the task of actual `fork()` system call, that is, creating child process and returning the pid, and some more additional functionalities.

I am not able to figure out how to do that. I checked the kernel source code for `fork()` (fork.c) and could not figure out much.

Doing this:

```
dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,fork);  
int fork(void) {
    int pid=_fork(); // Trying to call actual fork does not work
    return pid;
}
```

How can I do that? Here is the link to kernel source code for fork: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/kernel/fork.c#L10

**Edit (pulled in from comments)**:

I am working on a leak detecting tool, and this tool detects a double free when a child process deletes the memory allocated by the parent. To overcome this i will override `fork()`, and whenever there is a `fork()`, the parent's memory allocation table will be duplicated to the child.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Runtime errors? Compiler errors?

Comment: @Simone: _fork( ); // Error: _fork was not declared. My idea was to make it hit the actual kernel version of fork and not mine. Hope it makes clear now.

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to accomplish by doing this? What's your end goal?

Comment: @Omnifarious: I want to add some functionalities to the existing fork( ) call, which will be used by one of my tool.

Comment: Why not use a macro? In the .c file: `int my_fork(void) { /* do stuff */; return fork(); }` And in the header: `extern int my_fork(void); #define fork my_fork`.

Comment: `the parent's memory allocation table will be duplicated to the child.` This is already how fork() works: the parent and child have identical copies of the memory map, but in different arenas. If the child free()s, the parent won't notice, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to call the actual `fork` with `syscall(SYS_fork)` after including `<sys/syscall.h>`. See `syscall(2)`.

Comment: I was not certain there was really a `fork` system call anymore. I thought it was translated to a `clone` call with a particular set of parameters.

Comment: @larsmans: That gives some good idea!! Great. Let me try that now and see if it works.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - It works...  It's probably fine, but I wouldn't do it that way. I would find a way to call the original `fork` function from libc. I think that solution is more robust over time.

Comment: @Omnifarious basically you're right. They're both syscalls and they both call `do_fork()`. Clone passes its parameters through, fork sets defaults. See http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/x86/kernel/process.c#L233 for example.

Comment: Making the syscall directly is a bad idea. `fork` is required to call `pthread_atfork` functions as well as performing some internal synchronization to prevent stdio/malloc state from being corrupt in the child with multi-threaded parents, update the robust mutex list pointer, etc...

Answer (score 8):

You aren't going to get anything useful from the kernel source code for `fork`. Your code will not be allowed to do the things the kernel does no matter what library trickery you manage. That's a hard boundary that cannot be breached without writing a kernel module.

All the library code for `fork` does is set things up and execute a special instruction that switches to kernel mode where the kernel's `fork` code executes. There is sort of a way to put this special instruction in your own code. It's the `syscall` function. Since `fork` takes no arguments, it should be relatively easy to use this function to make the system call.

But this is not what I recommend you do.  I recommend you do this instead:

```
typedef int (*forkfunc_t)(void);

int fork(void)
{
     forkfunc_t sysfork = (forkfunc_t)dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "fork");
     return sysfork();
}
```

Basically, whatever shared library hackery you do, you should basically find some way of retrieving the previous value of the `fork` function before you replace it with your own.

Comment: I am working on a leak detecting tool, and this tool detects a double free when a child process deletes the memory allocated by the parent. To overcome this i will override fork( ), and whenever there is a fork( ), the parent's memory allocation table will be duplicated to the child.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Ahh, so you don't need to modify what the kernel is doing with `fork`, you just need to make sure you intercept it and wrap it appropriately. That's very doable, and your shared library technique isn't too bad of a way to go about it.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I edited your comment into your question as it is quite an important piece of information! If you're not happy with it, go ahead and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hacking badly, anyway, why not just use a macro

```
#define fork() (spoon(),fork())
```

or

```
#define fork() spoon(fork())
```

where `spoon` is then function that does the things that you want to accomplish.

The preprocessor is guaranteed not to do recursion and leave the `fork` inside the expasion alone.

Comment: my problem was not how to overload fork( ). I have been able to overload it using "dlsym" sys call. My problem was how to replicate the work of fork( ), anyways i have been able to achieve that now using the larsman's suggestion and my problem is solved. Thatnks anyways.